# What is the relationship between repunits and their prime factors?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I realized that all repunits that have a prime amount of $1s$ seem to follow these properties:

1. If $n$ is prime, then $R(n-1)$ has $n$ as a factor

Example with $n=13$:

$111111111111 (R12)$ is divisible by $13$

2. If $n$ is prime, then the prime factors of $Rn$ have the form $(n*k + 1)$

Example with $n=17:$

$11111111111111111 (R17) = 2071723 · 5363222357$

$2071723 = 17 · 121866 + 1$

$5363222357 = 17 · 315483668 + 1$

Is there an explanation on these possible properties? They only seem to work with primes, and do not hold with repunits that have a composite number of 1s.

I assume the first one has something to do with Fermat's primality test but i have no clue about the second one

Many thanks

Comment: Hint (for the first part):  $R(n)=\frac 19\times (10^n-1)$

Comment: Hint (for the second part):  Note that it isn't quite true.  $3\,|\,111$ for example.  But aside from $3$, show that, for any prime divisor $q$ of $R(p)$, $p$ is the order of $10\pmod q$, so $p\,|\,q-1$.

Comment: @lulu Thank you, I understand the first part , it is definitively Fermat’s little theorem. I was not able to understand the second part, why does not work with 3 but it does with any other prime?